# Highcharts Xaxis formatting issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts, formatting

I have been facing this issue for a while and had found a fix too, but apparently this same issue has popped up again

So my visualization has a few drop downs and a chart (highcharts.js) which keeps changing dynamically depending on drop down selections
Xaxis - date  and yaxis - Metric value and YOY value (column and line charts)

There is one dropdown namely "Daily" and "Hourly" which is in sync with my backend
For daily - data is for 14 days, and for hourly it's for 14*24 hours

So, with my codes used here, Xaxis comes correctly for the daily part showing 14 days(bars) there
**But for Hourly, xaxis gets messed up and it counts each hour as a day and therefore shows me days for 14*24 like in the image below**

[image: Wrong graph - Xaxis]

So, I had already solved this problem by adding the following code in another tab :

```
xAxis: {
            type : 'datetime',


            min : Date.UTC(new Date(processed_json[0][0]).getYear(),new Date(processed_json[0][0]).getMonth(),new Date(processed_json[0][0]).getDate()),
            max : Date.UTC(new Date(processed_json[processed_json.length - 1][0]).getYear(),new Date(processed_json[processed_json.length - 1][0]).getMonth(),new Date(processed_json[processed_json.length - 1][0]).getDate()),
            dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                second : '%H:%M',
                minute : '%H:%M',
                hour : '%H:%M',
                day : '%e %b',
                week : '%e',
                month : '%b',
                year : '%e'
                    },
plotOptions: {
            series: {
            pointStart: Date.UTC(new Date(processed_json[0][0]).getYear(),new Date(processed_json[0][0]).getMonth(),new Date(processed_json[0][0]).getDate()),
            pointInterval :  3600 * 1000, // 3600*1000 for hourly
            tickInterval :   3600 * 1000,
                }
            },
```

The "min","max" and "pointstart" take care that the graph comes like this as follows :

[image: Correct Graph - Xaxis]

But, now I am using the same code in a new tab and getting Wrong graph again even after using - min, max and pointstart same as above.

I really am unable to understand this, if everything (processed_json, others etc) are exactly same, why am I getting this issue again?
Can someone suggest another method or tell me what I am doing wrong.

EDIT :

Also, I would like to add this functionality that when it zooms in the correct graph (2nd one), then it should show each hour in the xaxis. Is this feasible? If yes, how?

Comment: If it works for one chart but doesn't for second, then maybe AJAX response is different? About ticks - use [`tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) to change logic for that, then use [`labels.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) to use specific format on ticks.

Comment: Yes, this could solve the problem but I will have to write a specific code with respect to the dates I have.
I am trying a couple of examples in tickPositioner, but still not getting results I need. can you help me with that? 
Also, I dont understand how AJAX response comes into play here.Can you elaborate on that ?

Comment: I think I solved this problem, the problem was in some other place!
Thanks anyways.

Comment: To call AJAX use [`selection event`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.selection) - after this you can call AJAX and set new data for series.